# Why async dependency injection in Dagger2 is not working?

Tags: android, dagger-2, rx-java2

I have dependency injection in method and it was quite slow that is why
I tried to inject dependencies async, but it's not working properly.
I have some logs in the featuredCalendar() it prints log "step1"
but doesn't print "step2"

```
@Singleton 
@Provides 
fun apiDaysSeResource(retrofit: Retrofit): Observable<ApiDaysSeResource{ 
return Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe<ApiDaysSeResource> { 
retrofit.create<ApiDaysSeResource>(ApiDaysSeResource::class.java) 
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
}

public interface ApiDaysSeResource {
@GET("dagar.json?")
Single<FeaturedCalendar> days(@Query("fran") String fran, @Query("till") String till, @Query("key") String key, @Query("id") String id);
}



@Singleton
@Provides
 fun vacationRepository(apiDaysSeResource: Observable<ApiDaysSeResource>): VacationRepository {
return VacationRepository(apiDaysSeResource)


 }




class VacationRepository(private val apiDaysSeResource: Observable<ApiDaysSeResource>) {
fun featuredCalendar(from: String, till: String, key: String, id: String): Flowable<FeaturedCalendar> {
Log.i("time_test", " step1")
return apiDaysSeResource.flatMapSingle { apiDaysSeResource ->
  Log.i("time_test", " step2")
  apiDaysSeResource.days(from, till, key, id)
}.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solve my problem I did some small changes
and also have a look at this sample
https://github.com/frogermcs/Dagger2Recipes-AsyncInjection

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun apiDaysSeResource(retrofit:Retrofit):ApiDaysSeResource{
return retrofit.create(ApiDaysSeResource::class.java)}

 @Singleton
@Provides
fun  apiDaysSeResourceObservable(apiDaysResource: Lazy<ApiDaysSeResource>): Observable<ApiDaysSeResource> {
return Observable.defer { Observable.just(apiDaysResource.get()) }
  }
```

Comment: Dagger2 support async injection, take a look at https://google.github.io/dagger/producers.html